# If f is monotone, then $\int_{L+a}^L f(x) dx=K$ has a unique solution for L

Tags: calculus

As the title states, I have to prove that if $f(x)$ is monotone and if  $$\int_{L+a}^Lf(x) dx=K$$ has a solution $r$ so that $$\int_{r+a}^rf(x)dx=K,$$ then $r$ is unique. I feel that this is obvious if I consider the integral to be the area under the curve. Clearly there is no other solution to it but I do not see how to prove this rigorously.

Thanks

Comment: WHether the solution exists define on $K$ and $a$. For example if $K=2$ and $a=1$, take $f$ to be the constant function $1$. Then you cannot find such an $r$. Also uniqueness is not guaranteed by considering constant function.

Comment: oh I think I phrased my question poorly. I should have said "if it has a solution. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that uniqueness is not guaranteed if you allow constant function $f$. If $f$ is strictly monotone, then you can consider the change of variable $\tau = t + (s-r)$

$$\int^r_{r+a} f(t)dt = \int^s_{s+a} f(\tau+ r-s)d\tau\ . $$